# django .env file not working like the tutorial explains it

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm following the django heroku tutorial. I'm at the point 'Define config vars'. I've imported in my views.py

```
import os
```

and modified it like so

```
def index(request):
    times = int(os.environ.get('TIMES',3))
    return HttpResponse('Hello! ' * times)
```

I created a .env file

```
python-getting-started\
    getting-started\
    hello\
    .env
```

the tutorial says

```
heroku local will automatically set up the environment based on 
the contents   of the .env file in your local directory. 
Edit the .env file to add:TIMES=2
If you run the app with heroku local, you’ll see two “Hello!”’s.
```

After I altered it I still see 'Hello' three times. I restarted the local server three times but that didn't work. i want to get this to work so I can remove all the hard coded things that need to be variables, so my app is secure. What am I missing? All guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just want to make sure. Is `TIMES` set in your env variables?  You can do `heroku config:get TIMES` to check it out.  If it isn't set, you have two options.  Setting the variables via the command line or in herokus web app.

Lastly, if all that is done.  Check if your local env files and your heroku config vars are the same (unless you are purposely running two different settings).